# Ошибка в коде PHP при работе с PDO

Tags: php

Имеется следующий код:

```
class Database {
  private $host = "192.168.104.171";
  private $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host;
}

$db = new Database;
```

Получаю такую ошибку:
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: На сколько мне известно php не поддерживает выражения в определении свойств. Вы можете сделать это в конструкторе

Comment: @AntonKucenko Это можно даже как ответ писать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько мне известно php не поддерживает выражения в определении свойств.

Вы можете сделать это в конструкторе.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Database {
  private $dsn;

  public function __construct($driver, $host) {
    $this->dsn = "{$driver}:host={$host}";
  }
}

$db = new Database('mysql', '192.168.104.171');
```